# Using SASS how to prevent a css file from being generated inside of the SASS folder?

Tags: css, sass, codekit

I'm using SASS, and have Codekit installed.With Codekit I tell the scss files to compress and compile into css inside of the ../css folder.

```
css
    style.css
sass
    style.css
    style.scss
```

Something somewhere is telling that scss file to also export out a css file into my sass folder.

*Codekit is setup correctly:*

[image]

*Output: (there should be no css files here)*

[image]

Anyone else run into this issue?

---

**What I've found out so far:**

The problem does not seem to have anything to do with Codekit, cause the annoying `.css` file will get generated inside of my `SASS` folder even with Codekit uninstalled.

I use to have LiveReload and LiveStyle installed, but I've removed both of those items.

I started a brand new project in a different folder, so far have not been able to reproduce issue, however still experience bug with my real project.

PyCharm seems to be generating the css files! Looking into how to turn that off now Thank to [Katie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/327466/katiek)

[image]

Comment: I believe I found the problem, I had installed the Emmet LiveStyle plugin http://livestyle.emmet.io/ just read about it in this google post here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/compass-users/XdApDZEGyXQ I had installed it, but never really used it. Basically if you edit CSS in the Chrome console it should actually update your css files too.

Comment: I found the problem(Edit no I didn't), I had installed the Emmet LiveStyle package [livestyle.emmet.io](http://livestyle.emmet.io/) in Sublime Text 2/3. Just read about it in this google post here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/compass-users/XdApDZEGyXQ I had installed it, but never really used it. Basically if you edit CSS in the Chrome console it should actually update your css files too. I never used the plugin so I just uninstalled it from **[Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/)** and the annoying problem is solved!

Comment: wait damn it, those stupid files are back ;(

Comment: ok this bug is DRIVING ME INSANE, like that fly in the episode Fly on Breaking Bad. WHY ARE YOU SAVING A CSS FILE IN THE SASS FOLDER! Just uninstalled Codekit and uninstalled and reinstalled SASS via terminal

Comment: ok so the CSS file inside of the SASS folder is not controlled by Codekit, something else is generating it

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: Sublime Text 2.0.2, I had the LiveStyle package installed, I thought that was causing the problem so I removed it. I added more notes, stuff I've found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's happening without Codekit as a factor, you may have something odd in your config.rb file.  In the root directory of your project (probably the directory that contains the css and sass directories), open the file config.rb in your text editor (Sublime Text). Look for these lines:

```
css_dir = something
sass_dir = something
```

These lines tell Sass where to put the resulting files. It sounds like you want it like this:

```
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "sass"
```

Comment: Oh we did have a config.rb file for our old project which isn't being used anymore... deleted those files. The project is in Python, I now suspect that PyCharm (my editor is generating the css files) Looking into it now :)

Comment: Ok your Answer helped point me in the right direction! PyCharm > Preferences > File Watchers (unchecked SASS) thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Rename style.scss to _style.scss it will solve your problem. smae thing is done with normalize.scss and reset.scss you can see.

Comment: Thanks, but actually it was a setting in PyCharm that was doing it, their watchers were monitoring any SASS file in my project